# Override function for multiple Inheritance hierarchies

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two class hierarchies

```
A -> X -> Z
B -> Y -> Z
```

X, Y and Z are Library Functions and so they are unchangeable.

Z has a function **myfunc()**

Now i want to add some code to **myfunc()** when it is called on a A or B instance.

How can i change my Inheritance hierarchy that i've to implement the additional code only once? Is there any pattern?

Comment: Add the code to `C` and call `C` out of `A` and `B` respectively? Dirty but non-changing.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? There's the default implementation feature.

Comment: Then do as Smutje described, it's called delegation.

Comment: Can't use plain old method overriding? Or am I confused?

Comment: no because a base class for A+B would need to extend X+Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably factor out your new implementation of myfunc() to a delegate object, and override myfunc to point to the delegate. Here is an example.

```
class MyFuncDelegate() {
    static void myFunc() {
        // your code
    }
}

class A {
    void myFunc() {
        super.myFunc();
        Delegate.myFunc();
    }
}
```

B can then use the same pattern. Not very object-oriented, avoids repeating yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Use delegation to implement the new functionality. This not only solves your problem, but also adds some seams for testing.

```
class A extends X {
    private ZDelegate delegate;

    public A(ZDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public R myFunc(P param) {
        return delegate.myFunc(this, param);
    }
}

public class ZDelegate {
    public R myFunc(Z z, P param) {
        //your code
        z.myFunc(param);
        //your code
        //return something...
    }
}
```

You have a new class (ZDelegate) with a clear, single responsibility: Enhancing myFunc.

The seams for testing are: You can test your new myFunc independently of everything else. And you can test your A and B objects independently from ZDelegate. You can do both either with fakes or mock objects.

Your A and B objects are still very closely coupled to X, Y and Z though...